# Plotting a NumericQ-protected function with the attribute HoldAll fails

Tags: plotting, bugs, evaluation, core-language

**Fixed in 12.1**

---

This works:

```
ClearAll[f1];
f1[x_] /; NumericQ[x] := x;
Plot[f1[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

This does not:

```
ClearAll[f2];
SetAttributes[f2, HoldAll];
f2[x_] /; NumericQ[x] := x;
Plot[f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

However, `Table` works:

```
Table[f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]
(*  {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25}  *)
```

> ***Q: Why?***

P.S. These also fail (blank plots):

```
Plot3D[y^2 + f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
ContourPlot[y^2 + f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
DensityPlot[y^2 + f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

But these succeed:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, f2[x]^2}, {x, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[{x, f2[x]^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

One might test other plotters, but let's focus on `Plot`.

I get the same results for `f2[x_?NumericQ] := x`.

I'm using V12. The behavior is probably version-dependent.

Comment: This is just a bug that will probably be fixed in the next release. Diving into the "why" and finding workarounds might be academically interesting, but it's not behavior that needs to be explained in terms of the intended design of the functionality.

Comment: @user6014 Thanks. For some reason, I didn't even consider it might be a bug.

Comment: @user6014 Please go ahead and add the [tag:bugs] tag and header in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in 12.1

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
ClearAll[x, f1];
f1[x_] /; NumericQ[x] := x;
Plot[f1[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]

ClearAll[f2, x];
SetAttributes[f2, HoldAll];
f2[x_] /; NumericQ[x] := x;
Plot[f2[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]
```